# opencv framework for iOS error

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am trying to build the opencv framework for Xcode. I am new to the Mac world as well as opencv. I followed the instructions as given on

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html

I cloned the repository (opencv 2.4.7) and then tried running the python script - as per the instruction on the link

python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios

I get the below error, can someone please help? I am using OSX 10.8.5

> ```
> Applications/gebos_third_party_apps/opencv/3rdparty/zlib/gzwrite.c:84:15:
> ```
>
> note: did you mean 'fwrite'? got = write(state->fd, strm->next_in,
>   strm->avail_in); ^~~~~ fwrite In file included from
>   /Applications/gebos_third_party_apps/opencv/3rdparty/zlib/gzwrite.c:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/gebos_third_party_apps/opencv/3rdparty/zlib/gzguts.h:21:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:252:9:
> ```
>
> note: 'fwrite' declared here size_t fwrite(const void * __restrict,
>   size_t, size_t, FILE * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS(fwrite); ^
>   /Applications/gebos_third_party_apps/opencv/3rdparty/zlib/gzwrite.c:573:9:
>   error: implicit declaration of function 'close' is invalid in C99
>   [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration] if (close(state->fd) == -1)
>   ^ 2 errors generated.
>
> ```
> ** INSTALL FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed: CompileC /Applications/gebos_third_party_apps/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-x86_64/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/zlib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/gzwrite.o
> ```
>
> 3rdparty/zlib/gzwrite.c normal x86_64 c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler CompileC
>   /Applications/gebos_third_party_apps/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-x86_64/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/zlib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/gzlib.o
>   3rdparty/zlib/gzlib.c normal x86_64 c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler CompileC
>   /Applications/gebos_third_party_apps/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-x86_64/3rdparty/zlib/OpenCV.build/Release-iphonesimulator/zlib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/gzread.o
>   3rdparty/zlib/gzread.c normal x86_64 c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (3 failures) Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File
>   "opencv-lib/opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 112, in
>   
>   build_framework(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),
>   "../..")), os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])) File
>   "opencv-lib/opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 104, in
>   build_framework put_framework_together(srcroot, dstroot) File
>   "opencv-lib/opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 80, in
>   put_framework_together shutil.copytree(tdir0 +
>   "/install/include/opencv2", dstdir + "/Headers") File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
>   line 168, in copytree names = os.listdir(src) OSError: [Errno 2] No
>   such file or directory:
>   '../build/iPhoneOS-arm64/install/include/opencv2'

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, the best way around this, other than fixing the zlib warnings directly, is to add `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` to your C_FLAGS ... this can added to build_framework.py in the cmakeargs list as `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=\"-Wno-implicit-function-declaration\"`:

```
cmakeargs = ("-GXcode " +
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release " +
            "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=\"-Wno-implicit-function-declaration\" " +
            "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%s/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-%s_Xcode.cmake " +
            "-DBUILD_opencv_world=ON " +
            "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install") % (srcroot, target)
```

.....

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. The suggested edit to the install instructions mentioned here (http://code.opencv.org/issues/3587) fixed it for me. Specifically, cd to the directory containing build_framework.py and run the install from there with a fully qualified destination directory.

i.e.:

```
cd ~/<my_working_directory>/opencv/platforms/ios/
python build_framework.py ~/<my_working_directory>/ios
```

The other note worth mentioning is that as of my testing, it is no longer necessary to create the Developer symlink in the root directory.